# Keyboard inputs extremely slow

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Got a wild one.

I build and maintain [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chatstrike-recruit/chligdkhjbmcdacnbhdgfkmnooofgmli)

I have exposed some of the source code [HERE](https://gitlab.com/fresheyeball/ce-debug/-/tree/master) for your review.

Which contains some `<input>`s and a `<textarea>` tag. For some reason on one customer's computer, these inputs take **seconds** to respond to keyboard input. However, copy pasting text, works *sometimes*. And here is the kicker:

## IF the chrome developer tools are open AND the chrome developer tools are currently recording performance, the problem doesn't happen at all.

---

### User's Computer

- MacOS
- Tested in normal Chrome
- Tested in normal Chrome with all other extensions disabled
- Tested in incognito chrome (with no other extensions)

The bug has shown itself in all of the above.

- Tested unadorned `<textarea>` in jsfiddle, and there was no problem

### The Extension

Does not listen for `"keyup"` or `"input"` events on the `<textarea>`. Only certain `<input>`s are effected. The `<textarea>` is effected. Even though the extension JavaScript code is completely idle.

The extension is coded in vanilla JavaScript, with no libraries (ok we include tippy) or pre-processors.

### Other Machines

The problem is not reproducible on any machines I have access to. Including other Mac's, Linux, or Windows machines. It's only happening to the one user.

---

The fact that recording performance, magically fixes the bug, is a real vexing issue here. Since the very tool I would use to determine why the `<textarea>` keyboard inputs are so slow, itself fixes the issue.

Out of ideas over here. Please help.

Comment: *affected. Incredible. Could you show the code for the problem input / textareas ?

Comment: This is a known bug with an external display on MacOS, https://crbug.com/971701.

Comment: @George I have added a link to the code in the post.

Comment: Did you try other Chromium browsers at your client's Mac, like MS Edge Chromium to see if this occurs?

Comment: Nothing jumps out of the code for me, and can't test, obviously.  I think @wOxxOm may have the right issue.  Check if this is happening on the main or an auxiliary (whether external or not) monitor.  If auxiliary, move the window to the main monitor.  Alternatively, try turning off your transitions and animations and see if the problem persists.  Best luck!

Comment: It seems that everything is right.  I'm not sure if that affects but try to reorder or use one the  'input.addEventListener' `keyup` and `change`. Good luck!

Comment: @i_thamary the effected element is a textarea, so that doesn't work

Comment: @wOxxOm I checked, and no external display is involved.

Comment: did you get it resolved ? please update question or add an answer if its solved. now im also curious about this bug...

Comment: @nikhilswami unfortunately no, I have not gotten it resolved. I am trying to get an RDP debugging session setup with the customer.

Answer (score 2):

i also experienced such strange issues where there was an anomaly on only one computer. its most likely due to tweaked chrome settings by other extensions and not cleaning the junk after uninstalling.

if you tried to reproduce the issue and id did not reappear then problem is definitely with the system. so uninstall and reinstall the browser and remove all traces. and install latest version of chrome.

as you mentioned its mac, if its an old mac with slow performance overall due to ageing then its excusable. as device speeds vary greatly in real world depending on the system load. even tho you mentioned it fixes the issue but still consider similar cases of windows PCs.

you might also want to check this line 1166(i just suspect):

```
function setupStateListeners(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    for (const inp of document.querySelectorAll("input")) {
      inp.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        setState(e.target.id, e.target.value); //chatstrike is good ext ;-)
      });
    }
    for (const inp of document.querySelectorAll("select")) {
      inp.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        setState(e.target.id, e.target.value);
      });
    }
    restoreState();
  }, 200);
};
```

even tho the issue persists , then your last resort would be to reset the mac to factory default (kind of reset in windows).

Comment: if i sound trivial please excuse, as sometimes trivial solutions work for the biggest problems. also ask the client to check it on chromium based browsers where the extension is compatible...